# vb.net: App with open dialog shows up twice in taskbar

Tags: vb.net, dialog, icons, taskbar, showdialog

I have an app, which sometimes shows dialogs using the ShowDialog-Command. When the Dialog is open, the App shows up twice in the taskbar. Is there an option to suppress the second instance there, since the calling instance is not available anyway?

One can suppress it using `FormBorderStyle=None` or `ShowinTaskbar = False` but i am looking for a more global approach for the whole app without defining theese properties for every dialog.

Comment: This question could be answered simply by reading the documentation for the `Form` class, or even just looking through the Properties window. There's a dedicated property for this purpose that you would have found if you'd done that. You should never be posting here without reading the documentation first so this question should never have been posted.

Comment: To do it globally, you could subclass the dialogs, set the properties you've mentioned in the sub class, then change the code references to use your subclass.   Or maybe implement a global method for showing dialogues.  Any more efficient than just updating existing references, can't say